# Not the same font when i send the project to someone else C# Visual studio

Tags: c#

I made a calculator (my first project) and i used my own fonts. The problem is that i see it as i made it on my computer, but anyone else that i send the project to (file from projects, or as an installation), the fonts are changed. The project is made in Visual Studio. I tried many things, but i have yet to find the answer to my problem, so i hope that someone could help me.

-Font: http://www.dafont.com/obelixpro.font

Comment: how about changing to the system font?

Comment: I can, but i would like the way to make it work with this font, and it looks better with the font that i am using, and no, the y do not have. :)

Comment: Yes :) how do i do that ? or just make it as a bundle as a application, without the install.